Rename dataframe columns based dictionary and startswith
So in my the data I work with, there are columns that often have date updated at the end of its name, but always start the same. Also, the column name sometimes very long, so to work with it, I want to rename it. I can't use indexes as there is the chance order can be changed.
So for example, consider this df:
data = {"name related (22/05/2024)": ["Rhaenyra", "Daemon", "Aegon II", "Aemond"], 
    "team (updated 22/05/2024)": ["Team Black", "Team Black", "Team Green", "Team Green"],
    "name of the dragon (updated 22/05/2024)": ["Syrax", "Caraxes", "Sunfyre", "Vhagar"]}



    name related (22/05/2024)   team (updated 22/05/2024)   name of the dragon (updated 22/05/2024)
0   Rhaenyra    Team Black  Syrax
1   Daemon  Team Black  Caraxes
2   Aegon II    Team Green  Sunfyre
3   Aemond  Team Green  Vhagar

I have many more columns. I want to rename them with keys if they start with the values of the dictionary, e.g.:
col_names_for_renaming = {"NAME":"name related", "TEAM":"team", "DRAGON":"name of the dragon"}

Expected:
    NAME    TEAM    DRAGON
0   Rhaenyra    Team Black  Syrax
1   Daemon  Team Black  Caraxes
2   Aegon II    Team Green  Sunfyre
3   Aemond  Team Green  Vhagar


could you just iterate over the column names and remove the date part?

Use df.rename(columns=?) with a function that returns the new name by scanning the rename mapping dict:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "name related (22/05/2024)": ["Rhaenyra", "Daemon", "Aegon II", "Aemond"],
        "team (updated 22/05/2024)": [
            "Team Black",
            "Team Black",
            "Team Green",
            "Team Green",
        ],
        "name of the dragon (updated 22/05/2024)": [
            "Syrax",
            "Caraxes",
            "Sunfyre",
            "Vhagar",
        ],
    }
)


col_names_for_renaming = {
    "NAME": "name related",
    "TEAM": "team",
    "DRAGON": "name of the dragon",
}


def column_renamer(old_name):
    for k, v in col_names_for_renaming.items():
        if old_name.startswith(v):
            return k
    # return the old name if no new name found
    return old_name


df = df.rename(columns=column_renamer)

print(df)

Output:
       NAME        TEAM   DRAGON
0  Rhaenyra  Team Black    Syrax
1    Daemon  Team Black  Caraxes
2  Aegon II  Team Green  Sunfyre
3    Aemond  Team Green   Vhagar


You could use a regex to match and map the substitutions:
import re

# reverse dictionary
dic = {k: v for v,k in col_names_for_renaming.items()}
# {'name related': 'NAME', 'team': 'TEAM', 'name of the dragon': 'DRAGON'}

pat = '|'.join(map(re.escape, dic))
c = df.columns.to_series()
df.columns = (c.str.extract(fr'^({pat})', expand=False)
               .map(dic).fillna(c)
              )

Output:
       NAME        TEAM   DRAGON
0  Rhaenyra  Team Black    Syrax
1    Daemon  Team Black  Caraxes
2  Aegon II  Team Green  Sunfyre
3    Aemond  Team Green   Vhagar

